# Can the Ubuntu download be booted?

Tags: boot

Using a different PC then the target Ubuntu PC I downloaded Ubuntu and copied the downloaded file to a DVD thinking that I should be able to boot from it on the target PC.

The target PC has Windows installed but has been corrupted and is not operational.  My intent was to format the hard drive and totally replace Windows with Ubuntu however, I cannot boot from the DVD.

I changed the boot process in the Bios to boot from the CD/DVD but Windows keeps booting up.

Is the downloaded file bootable or do I need to do something else.

Thank you.

---

Comment: If you downloaded the ISO file from https://www.ubuntu.com/download/desktop for example, it should bootable. Probably your DVD is defective or you didn't burn the ISO file correctly. Try to look at the contents of this DVD in your other PC. Please follow the tutorials: https://tutorials.ubuntu.com/tutorial/tutorial-burn-a-dvd-on-windows

Comment: Thank you for the info.  I copied the downloaded image instead of burning it to the DVD.  Will give that a try once it completes.

Comment: "and copied the downloaded file to a DVD". You have to write the iso9660 file system direct to the disc, not copy the file containing it on to a disc. What you've done is like putting a picture of a meal on the table to eat, rather than the meal -- we've probably all made this mistake when first writing .iso files. The tutorial above is good, you need to "burn the disc image".

Comment: All the above but if you can, use a USB instead. Installing from DVD is annoyingly slow by comparison.

Comment: This time I did burn the file (and did a verify ) to the DVD, however, it still will not boot up.  I suspect that there may be a problem with the DVD drive.  My next question is what do I need to do to get the .iso file to a USB Stick?. Can it just be copied?

Comment: Now I am trying to copy the downloaded file to a USB and am getting a message stating, "The file ubuntu-18.04.2-desktop-amd64" has properties that can't be copied to the new location", the location being the USB stick.  I can proceed here but need to know if this is normal.  Thx.

Comment: UEFI only USB key, just extract ISO ( 7 zip or similar) to FAT32 formated flash & set boot flag.
http://askubuntu.com/questions/395879/how-to-create-uefi-only-bootable-usb-live-media  Otherwise you have to use an installer that formats drive or uses dd to create a hybrid DVD/flash drive image. Flash drive then is not a normally partitioned or formatted drive. Lots of info on USB boot for installing
https://help.ubuntu.com/community/Installation/FromUSBStick

Comment: OK, I tried to what seemed to be the easiest way.  Formated the USB to FAT32.  Unzipped the downloaded Ubuntu file to the USB.  Everything seem to go fine except for 1 error stating "2-Boot-NoEmul.img" file.

Comment: Disregarding that error, attempted to boot the other PC from the USB. An error message stating that "An operating system wasn't found.  Try disconnecting any drives that don't contain an operating system".

Isn't there a very simple step-by-step process (without having to digest all of the informamtion everyone so kindly provided in the various links to take a Ubuntu file that was downloaded to a Windows 10 system and prepare it to be loaded onto a totally different PC where it is OK to overwrite whatever is there.

Comment: I have a clean DVD and USB stick, and have downloaded Rufus trying the various options and nothing seems to work.

Any more suggestions please.